# Pronunciation of "поздно" (late)

Tags: произношение

The word [поздно](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE) (late) is pronounced as [ˈpoznə]. So the д is not spoken. I do not understand why the д vanishes here in this case. Which grammar rule tells me this?

Comment: I do not know, why one would start learning language from such unimportant rules, like vowel reduction and silent consonants. It is like starting learning English from words like twony, gotta, etc. If you pronounce these consonants, you still will sound correct.

Comment: @Anixx why do you think the OP just started learning Russian? or was that a general remark?

Answer (score 4):

Quite a few consonant clusters have silent letters in them, e.g.:

- з**д**н (пра́з**д**ник, пра́з**д**новать, по́з**д**ний, по́з**д**но, бе́з**д**на, звёз**д**ный), silent **д**.
- с**т**н (ле́с**т**ница, до́блес**т**ный, захолу́с**т**ный, я́рос**т**ный), silent **т**.
- с**т**л (счас**т**ли́вый, со́вес**т**ливый, уча́с**т**ливый), silent **т**.
- с**т**с (раси́с**т**ский, национали́с**т**ский), silent **т**.

[Some sources](https://russianschoolrussificate.com/tip/russian-silent-consonants/) claim a silent **т** in the н**т**с / н**д**с cluster but [Avanesov's dictionary](https://povto.ru/russkie/slovari/orfoepicheskie/avanesov/orfoepicheskij-avanesov-1988_0023.htm) recommends the pronunciation [*нц<sup>с</sup>*]:

[image]

- н**д**с (голла́н**д**ский, шотла́н**д**ский, финля́н**д**ский).
- н**т**с (гига́н**т**ский, парла́мен**т**ский, аге́н**т**ство).

These words also have silent letters:

- со́**л**нце, се́р**д**це, пожа́лу**й**ста (but not пожа́луйте)
- здра́**в**ствуй, чу́**в**ство, but not я́вственный, нра́вственный or баловство́ (as pointed out by @Yellow_Sky below)

In [russiangram.com](https://russiangram.com), I used the following regex to cover the most common cases:

```
(?<left>[сзн])(?<silent>[дт])(?<right>[нлс])
```

Comment: In _я**в**ственный_, `в` is not silent, it's pronounced [f], just as in _нравственный_ or _баловство_.

Comment: агентство is missing?

Comment: @YellowSky, good spot, updated my answer.

Comment: @Anixx, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Grammar rules usually don't tell anything about pronunciation at all. You should just know that there are certain consonant clusters where it happens all the time (muted letter is in bold): со**л**нце, здра**в**ствуй, сер**д**це, чу**в**ство and where you can hear both forms, like, say, in "гиган**т**ский".

It's like asking - which grammar rules make some English speakers pronounce "often" with or without t.

In Russian, though, we usually can answer the question of why we should write the muted consonant after all. Usually because in a different form this consonant is pronounced. Such a word is called "проверочное слово". For instance:

- солнечный
- сердечный
- гигант
- опоздать (therefore "поздно")

Usually, when we don't have such words, we don't have a version with muted consonant as well. It's not a rule set in stone however, for some words, like, for instance "лес**т**ница" or "чу**в**ство" - we won't find any other modern Russian word justifying such spelling.

So, memorize. Just memorize - as I always advise anyone learning any language.

Comment: I always pronounce л in солнце

Comment: @Anixx it's safe to say you are in a minority here.

Comment: Hmm, when the teachers explained the silent consonant in this word, they sounded unnaturally and cut my ears, but usually I do not feel unnatural when people pronounce this word. Thus I assume the teachers pronounced it in unusual way.